# Checking private assembly

Tags: visual-studio

Private assembly can be used by only that application only. How to check that it is unavailable for other application? Whether intranet is needed or we can check it on single machine?

Comment: Hi abc, could you rephrase this.  What do you mean by unavailable? Intranet?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You Can't.

Long Answer: Declare your public members as internal instead and use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to make them visible to the assembly you want to grant access to. Just keep in mind that this is not a 100% "protection", other Assemblies can still consume your assembly through Reflection.